# How do I generate APP BTA KEY and SETHOSTTID KEY for Bronto

Tags: magento, bronto

I was trying to do the Bronto integration but not sure how to generate these keys.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

> To generate API Keys in Bronto, you need to be logged in as a user
>   with sufficient permissions and go to Home > Settings > Data Exchange,
>   here is a direct link: https://app.bronto.com/mail/pref/data_exchange/
>
> Once there, you will see a button in the lower right that says "Add
>   Access Token". Click it and fill out the form to generate the API Key.
>   For directions on filling out the form, check out this sample
>   tutorial:
>   https://app.bronto.com/mail/help/help_view/?k=mail:home:api_tracking:hom.

Source: http://dev.bronto.com/question/how-get-api-key

Comment: Thanks you .Support asked me to check the same place but im still not quite sure where to check  as they haven't mentioned anything related to above names there.I was wondering whether they use different name for APP BTA KEY and SETHOSTTID KEY .